# Magit becomes very slow in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, magit, helm

I am a on and off spacemacs user for a long time but I have recently started working on some bigger projects and so I started investing some more time into improving my workflow and in particular I have started using the git layer to get some neat magit commands which are much more convenient than running everything in command line.

However I have a problem when I use magit: at startup everything works fine but the more I use it the more every command starts taking time until it becomes practically unusable. When I reach this point, I can restart emacs and it starts working quickly again for a while, but soon enough the problem comes back. I am running everything on ubuntu 20.04 and I haven't been able to find anything online about this problem. It seems like magit and helm combine badly on windows leading to slow behavior, so I tried with the ivy layer instead of helm, but that did not solve it.

Here is what the profiler looks like, when i tried to stage a hunk in the project, after having kept emacs running for some time:

```
- command-execute                                               21876  81%
 - call-interactively                                           21876  81%
  - funcall-interactively                                       21876  81%
   - magit-stage                                                19915  74%
    - magit-apply-hunk                                          19915  74%
     - magit-apply-patch                                        19915  74%
      - magit-refresh                                           19899  74%
       - magit-refresh-buffer                                   19899  74%
        - apply                                                 19875  74%
         - magit-status-refresh-buffer                          19819  74%
          - magit-run-section-hook                              19810  73%
           - apply                                              19810  73%
            - magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream-or-recent              19006  70%
             - magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream                19006  70%
              - magit-insert-log                                18991  70%
               - magit-git-wash                                 18991  70%
                + #<compiled 0x1d3fb1d>                         18986  70%
                + magit-git-insert                                  5   0%
                magit-log-insert-child-count                        4   0%
            + magit-insert-unpulled-from-upstream                 436   1%
            + magit-insert-unstaged-changes                       168   0%
            + magit-insert-stashes                                 76   0%
            + magit-insert-status-headers                          62   0%
            + magit-insert-staged-changes                          62   0%
          + magit-section-show                                      9   0%
         + magit-section-goto-successor                            56   0%
      + magit-run-git-with-input                                   16   0%
   + spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching                           1244   4%
   + magit-next-line                                              384   1%
   + magit-previous-line                                          329   1%
   + magit-section-toggle                                           4   0%
+ magit-todos--async-when-done                                   4584  17%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                 130   0%
+ global-hl-line-highlight                                         78   0%
+ timer-event-handler                                              45   0%
+ ...                                                              30   0%
+ magit-section-update-highlight                                   20   0%
  evil--jump-hook                                                   4   0%
+ winner-save-old-configurations                                    3   0%
+ evil-repeat-post-hook                                             2   0%
```

Apparently the problem is with the `compiled command` which I have no idea what it is. Maybe it is worth mentioning that the project I am working on is pretty big (~100 branches and as many tags) albeit only a few of them are actually present locally. I also have an almost vanilla configuration of spacemacs, with only various layers installed but almost no custom settings, I am just loading the custom emacs mode for contributing to the software frama-c (file frama-c-recommended.el at the [following address](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/tree/2a38d846dc47e4f568f131907f19519cb2d5f53f/share/emacs))

Why does it becomes so slow, and how to fix that?

EDIT: I didn't see that I could explore the `compiled` item, so here is more complete result of the profiler

```
- command-execute                                               21876  81%
 - call-interactively                                           21876  81%
  - funcall-interactively                                       21876  81%
   - magit-stage                                                19915  74%
    - magit-apply-hunk                                          19915  74%
     - magit-apply-patch                                        19915  74%
      - magit-refresh                                           19899  74%
       - magit-refresh-buffer                                   19899  74%
        - apply                                                 19875  74%
         - magit-status-refresh-buffer                          19819  74%
          - magit-run-section-hook                              19810  73%
           - apply                                              19810  73%
            - magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream-or-recent              19006  70%
             - magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream                19006  70%
              - magit-insert-log                                18991  70%
               - magit-git-wash                                 18991  70%
                - #<compiled 0x1d3fb1d>                         18986  70%
                 - apply                                        18986  70%
                  - magit-log-wash-log                          18986  70%
                   - magit-wash-sequence                        18986  70%
                    - #<compiled 0x1957ab9>                     18986  70%
                     - apply                                    18986  70%
                      - magit-log-wash-rev                      15956  59%
                       - jit-lock-after-change                   6011  22%
                        - run-hook-with-args                     6003  22%
                           font-lock-extend-jit-lock-region-after-change               2984  11%
                       - put-text-property                       3008  11%
                        - jit-lock-after-change                  3000  11%
                         - run-hook-with-args                    3000  11%
                            font-lock-extend-jit-lock-region-after-change               1552   5%
                       - magit-delete-line                       2325   8%
                        - jit-lock-after-change                  2189   8%
                         - run-hook-with-args                    2189   8%
                            font-lock-extend-jit-lock-region-after-change               1461   5%
                         magit-format-ref-labels                   20   0%
                       + magit-section                             16   0%
                       + run-hook-with-args-until-success                 12   0%
                       + eieio-oref                                12   0%
                       + magit-insert-child-count                   8   0%
                       + eieio-oset                                 4   0%
                       + magit-log-format-margin                    4   0%
                + magit-git-insert                                  5   0%
                magit-log-insert-child-count                        4   0%
            + magit-insert-unpulled-from-upstream                 436   1%
            + magit-insert-unstaged-changes                       168   0%
            + magit-insert-stashes                                 76   0%
            + magit-insert-status-headers                          62   0%
            + magit-insert-staged-changes                          62   0%
          + magit-section-show                                      9   0%
         + magit-section-goto-successor                            56   0%
      + magit-run-git-with-input                                   16   0%
   + spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching                           1244   4%
   + magit-next-line                                              384   1%
   + magit-previous-line                                          329   1%
   + magit-section-toggle                                           4   0%
+ magit-todos--async-when-done                                   4584  17%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                 130   0%
+ global-hl-line-highlight                                         78   0%
+ timer-event-handler                                              45   0%
+ ...                                                              30   0%
+ magit-section-update-highlight                                   20   0%
  evil--jump-hook                                                   4   0%
+ winner-save-old-configurations                                    3   0%
+ evil-repeat-post-hook                                             2   0%
```

Comment: For clarity, are you saying that this is only slow if you're using Spacemacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not Magit guy. But looks you need avoid calling `magit-refresh`.

The easiest way is to turn on `magit-inhibit-refresh`. Here is definition of `magit-apply-patch`,

[image]

Disable `magit-refresh` inside `magit-apply-patch` temporarily,

```
(defun my-magit-apply-patch-hack (orig-func &rest args)
  (let* ((magit-inhibit-refresh t))
    (apply orig-func args)))
(advice-add 'magit-apply-patch :around #'my-magit-apply-patch-hack)
```

Or you can advice the caller of `magit-apply-patch`. Similar to the above code.

Or you can toggle the flag globally by `M-x my-toggle-magit-refresh`,

```
(defun my-toggle-magit-fresh ()
  "Toggle magit refresh flag."
  (interactive)
  (setq magit-inhibit-refresh (not magit-inhibit-refresh))
  (message "magit-inhibit-refresh=%s" magit-inhibit-refresh))
```

Comment: `magit-inhibit-refresh` looks like an internal use var which is sometimes let-bound to temporarily prevent Magit from initiating a refresh when doing so would not be productive.  It's not a user option intended to be set globally, and I believe it won't be very helpful to do that (refreshing is kinda important).

Comment: You can always manually `M-x magit-refresh` any time (the hotkey is `g` in `magit-status-mode`). Everyone has her own workflow. If someone want to batch stage multiple files without `magit-refresh`, then they have the freedom to change  this flag temporarily.

Comment: @phils , Lots of people are using https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html to override the function's  internal logic. That's even more radical than setting a global boolean flag used by a function. In Emacs, the software freedom is always fully respected. Users could do whatever they want to solve their own problems.

Comment: If you've set a non-nil `inhibit-magit-refresh` then that manual `M-x magit-refresh` won't do anything (which was partly my point).  You can certainly arrange that it's *not* inhibited for certain commands, but in the absence of your edit showing any way to do so, I didn't think the original answer was helpful.  You most likely want to let-bind the var in your advice example (otherwise you'd need to account for errors).

Comment: @phils, if you read the original question, OP's analysis has given the command and the bottleneck. My answer is just howto. It cuts off the 70% cpu computing time (according to OP's data), so the answer is helpful. `magit-stage` and other commands should be much faster and is still functional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to have done the trick. The global deactivation of `magit-inhibit-refresh` is not really a good option, because the buffer never updates, so I end-up not knowing the state I am in. But your other trick worked and I don't mind updating the buffer manually once in a while. I also deactivated the `magit-todo` option which was taking up a significant amount of time